# Can't use any function on connected database

Tags: r, sqlite

I can't use data in .db file I connected to:

```
install.packages("DBI")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("RSQLite")
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

Hospital_db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),"Hospital_Data")

dbListFields(Hospital_db)
```

Error:

```
dbListFields(Hospital_db)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListFields’ for signature ‘"SQLiteConnection", "missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table you want to list the fields in like so:

```
dbListFields(Hospital_db, "table_name")
```

Comment: It may be beneficial to readers to provide a bit more context into what you are doing here. Adding some explanation behind your code would be helpful for those who may not know what you are doing with this.